# TFS Build and Test Impact

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, build-automation

I'm playing around with the Test Impact feature of TFS build.
It seems like you cannot use this feature if you are using a .vsdmi file, but only if you use a .testsettings file (although the VSDMI file includes a reference to the test settings file).

I have allowed Test Impact in the test settings file, and so on the TFS build configuration.
The reason I need to use the VSDMi file is that I created a test  list that i want to be executed in CI. The problem is that all builds show "No Impacted Test" though I know there are some.

Am I missing something here? Please find attached the vsdmi file, the testsettings file and a snapshot of the TFS build configuration.

[image: Config]

Here is the content of the .testsettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Master" id="68af9170-92f5-49d8-83dd-827359a79042" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Common\Terra.Environment.Common.Data.Test\TpEnvFileParser\InputFiles\" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Common\Terra.Environment.Fake\FakeData\HSW\Resources" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Tpie.Engines.Build\Tpie.Engines.Build.Test\ExpectedFiles\" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Tpie.Engines.Build\Tpie.Engines.Build.Test\Resources\" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Common\Terra.Environment.Common.Model\bin\Debug\TerraEntitiesModel.ssdl" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Common\Terra.Environment.Common.Model\bin\Debug\TerraEntitiesModel.csdl" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Common\Terra.Environment.Common.Data.Test\PListFileParser\InputFiles\" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Common\Terra.Environment.Common.Model\bin\Debug\TerraEntitiesModel.msl" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Tpie.Client\Tpie.Client.Common.Test\ExcelParsers\InputFiles\" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\Tpie.Engines.Build\Tpie.Engines.Build.TestProgram\Templates\" />
  </Deployment>
  <Execution>
    <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
    <Timeouts runTimeout="1800000" testTimeout="300000" />
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
      <WebTestRunConfiguration testTypeId="4e7599fa-5ecb-43e9-a887-cd63cf72d207">
        <Browser name="Internet Explorer 7.0">
          <Headers>
            <Header name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" />
            <Header name="Accept" value="*/*" />
            <Header name="Accept-Language" value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
            <Header name="Accept-Encoding" value="GZIP" />
          </Headers>
        </Browser>
      </WebTestRunConfiguration>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
      <DataCollectors>
        <DataCollector uri="datacollector://Microsoft/TestImpact/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.TestImpactDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        </DataCollector>
      </DataCollectors>
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

And here is the .vsmdi file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestLists xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <TestList name="TPIE Auto Build" id="2cbc1525-8079-4959-a126-4d4fb8fdb803" parentListId="8c43106b-9dc1-4907-a29f-aa66a61bf5b6">
    <TestLinks>
      <TestLink id="ee8dae77-c23e-df6b-c6b5-4be930087750" name="LevelTestConditionGroupCheckCalculationDataTypeVoltageTest" storage="..\tpie.client\tpie.client.common.test\bin\debug\tpie.client.common.test.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <TestLink id="74441000-f8e5-ac1b-fbd6-bb94da0bf3ce" name="LevelPowerSequenceBlockCheckSequenceElementTest" storage="..\tpie.client\tpie.client.common.test\bin\debug\tpie.client.common.test.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <TestLink id="afb21bed-4eff-9f9f-7e58-c72e7d133b32" name="TestGetMiscEnvironmentVariables" storage="..\server\terra.binmatrix.server.test\bin\debug\terra.server.bl.test.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </TestLinks>
  </TestList>
  <TestList name="Lists of Tests" id="8c43106b-9dc1-4907-a29f-aa66a61bf5b6">
    <RunConfiguration id="68af9170-92f5-49d8-83dd-827359a79042" name="Master" storage="master.testsettings" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRunConfiguration, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </TestList>
</TestLists>
```

Thanks,
Busi

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit tricky, but it works.
If you want to run the test impact analysis you need to set `Disable Test = true` and `Analyse Test Impact = true`.

I have done the following

- create CI build type with the vsmdi
- setup the build to run the tests (Disable Tests = false)
- select the vsmdi
- run two or three builds to collect test data
- switch the flags like described above

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I'm afraid that your solution didn't work for me. I changed to Disable Tests = True, and it didn't do the trick, only disabled the test. I saw also that your 'copy to output folder' is set to true. I tried that as well, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below steps to run your test.

1. Make Disable Tests= False
2. Anyalyze Test Impact= true;
3. make sure that while running test your build is getting the test dll's from the specified location as mention in the vsmdi file.
4. while debugging your build log set Logging Verbosity=Diagnostic.
   through this you can see the log whether your build is getting test dll or not.